# dispose ruby class object

Tags: ruby

- how to dispose an object in ruby...?

```
class Designer
    def message
      "Hello, World!"
    end
end

c = Designer.new

c.dispose # this is not working... any idea... or any alternative...?
```

thnx...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Designer
    def message
      "Hello, World!"
    end
end

c = Designer.new

# something like dispose :)
c = nil

# and you can add something like this
GC.start
```